# Fail2ban + 'invalid byte sequence in UTF-8' - Block abusive request's IPs on nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, utf-8, devise, fail2ban

I have fail2ban running on my server with filters:

sshd, nginx-auth and nginx-login (https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/554-how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban)

The problem is that sometimes I have thousands of requests per hour on my devise/sessions/ controllers with that error

> invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

and apparently fail2ban is not stopping it, it is not blocking not even banning those ips at all.

My question is: is there any known filter that I could run to prevent such spam attacks - this activity surely appears on my access.log but none of these filters are detecting it as fraudulent requests?

BTW: fail2ban is working fine since I have hundreds of ips banned with the ssh filter.

Comment: what are the indicators that make you think that those requests should get banned?

Comment: @phoet how would someone make 4000 invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 requests to my devise/sessions controller being legit requests? like fail2ban ssh bans ips after x failed attempt, I would like to do the same on my devise  login manager (on a nginx server)

Comment: that very much depends on what those requests do and where they come from. ie google scraping malformed urls.